# Identify which loop you are hooking into; primary or secondary?

Tags: wp-query, loop, query, hooks, debug

What is the most efficient way to determine which loop I'm in?

I have a few plugins that alter the query by hooking into various parts of [`WP_Query::get_posts()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/query.php#L1919), through the usual suspects, ie [`posts_where`, `posts_join`, etc](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5/wp-includes/query.php#L2582). I don't want to effect every loop on every page though, so right now I'm running a [`debug_backtrace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) and checking for the existence of `the main()` or [`query_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/query_posts) function as necessary.

There has to be a more efficient way to identify the primary loop and sub-loops on each page. Something I keep missing when I pore over the query vars and other aspects of the request, something that's unique to each one. How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Any progress on this question? If you've found an answer elsewhere, come back here and post your solution as an answer for others to benefit.

Comment: see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28670/pre-get-posts-firing-on-every-query. Also I noticed that using [in_the_loop()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/in_the_loop) works too...

Answer (score 5):

Just a quick update that a new method `is_main_query()` has been introduced in WP 3.3.

#### Example:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'foo_modify_query_exclude_category' );
function foo_modify_query_exclude_category( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && ! $query->get( 'cat' ) )
    $query->set( 'cat', '-5' );
}
```

#### Resources:

- WPDevel: [New API in 3.3: is_main_query()](http://wpdevel.wordpress.com/2011/12/07/new-api-in-3-3-is_main_query/)
- Codex reference: [is_main_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_main_query)
- Related [Trac Ticket #18677](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18677)

Answer (score 0):

If secondary loops are called properly (i.e. by not mucking with `query_posts()`, and by setting a variable `$myloop` equal to `get_posts()` or `new WP_Query`), then identifying said loop is as simple as referencing the variable.

If you need to call a second loop from within the primary Loop, and you call `setup_postdata()` in the secondary loop, you may need to call `wp_reset_query()` when you close your secondary loop, so that your template tags revert to applying to the primary Loop.

Comment: Thanks Chip, but I probably should have mentioned that the plugin is most likely unaware of its environment to that degree. I won't be responsible for every theme that the plugin is running in and unable to ensure that each one is using the loop appropriately.