# "pre_get_posts" firing on every query

Tags: wp-query, loop, pre-get-posts

How can I change arguments for the main query only, and not affect other queries?

```
add_filter('pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_count');
function custom_post_count($query){
  $query->set('posts_per_page', 5);
  return $query;
};
```

Because this action is called inside the get_posts method of WP_Query, this code will alter the *posts_per_page* argument for all loops, not just the main, so passing this argument to WP_Query is useless...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically what you are looking for is the **`global $wp_the_query`** variable which is set to the value of the main query. It may not be a perfect fit for 100% of cases but will probably work fine in 99% of cases:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_count' );
function custom_post_count( $query ){
  global $wp_the_query;
  if ( $wp_the_query === $query ) {
    $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
  }
  return $query;
};
```

Comment: Very nice trick!

Comment: I think Brian's method is much better. His code is self-documenting and uses the API, whereas this is unintuitive and vulnerable to changes in core.

Comment: @IanDunn: While it may be less intuitive to you, it is the *"official way"* to solve this problem. The WordPress team is [adding `is_main_query()` to 3.3](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18677) and it uses the same technique. Of course as there are many ways to solve the same problem in WordPress, Brian's solution is a good one too. Just avoid the use of `query_posts()` in your theme, as noted.

Comment: I had a problem where `if( is_tax('my_custom_tax') && is_main_query())` was firing in a second loop too in the footer, but just on those pages which displayed my_custom_tax in the main query. This solved my problem.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, 'pre_get_posts' is an action and not a filter. That's the main problem to start. Secondly, you need to set conditionals for the context.

```
add_action('wp', 'custom_post_count');
function custom_post_count($query){
    if($query->is_home || $query->is_front_page){
        $query->set('posts_per_page', 5);
    }
    return $query;
};
```

The previous example is if you want to use this once in your functions.php without touching your template files. As far as affecting every query, if you don't create a new query, every loop with inherit the pre_get_posts $query. That's why I use query_posts() to create a new query in the following example.

**Custom Loops**

This is how I do custom loops:

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 5
);
query_posts($args);

if(have_posts()): while(have_posts()): the_post();


endwhile; else:

endif;

wp_reset_query();
```

Just place query_posts() above the loop and wp_reset_query() at the end of the loop.

Hope this helps you out. :)

Comment: These conditionals are set inside custom loops too. For example I could have "recent posts" type of widget. Also, your code will work only if the custom loop is being made before the `wp` action

Comment: Updated my answer with the custom loops answer.

Comment: @Brian - **`query_posts()` is [not really recommended](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1753/when-should-you-use-wp-query-vs-query-posts-vs-get-posts)**, just fyi. One of the many problems with it is using it causes WordPress to make two database queries when it could have just made one.

Comment: Thanks Mike! I never knew the intricacies of this until I looked at your link and Rarst's fab graphic. I appreciate the tip.