# Filter for replacing the WP_query object for a given category

Tags: functions, wp-query, hooks

I'm looking for a action/filter to replace replace a category archive page with the contents of a page. I'm thinking of testing the category ID, and replacing the WP_Query object with a new one tailored for the page I want to grab, thus avoiding to have to modify the template.

Which filter/action could I use, and is there perhaps a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`template_redirect`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference):

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'my_category_template');

function my_category_template(){
  if(is_category(5)){ // <- category ID/title/slug
     require "path/to/your/template.php";
  }
}
```

If you only need to change the query arguments, then see Mike's answer to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28670/pre-get-posts-firing-on-every-query) question

Comment: I don't want to reuse a template, but to change the query parameters so that WordPress doesn't attempt to load the category archives, but the contents of a page.

Comment: See the linked question, check for `$query->is_category()` and add `$query->set('p', $your_page_id);`

Comment: My bad, I hadn't read that line. I've had some success with overriding `$wp_query` by returning a new `WP_Query` object with the query I want in that function, however the template doesn't pick it up. How could I access that in the template and isn't the loop supposed to pick it up automatically? If I do a `global $wp_query ; var_dump($wp_query)` in the template page it's not the same object the function is returning, if I `var_dump()` the object in the function context it seems to work fine, ie. it's the correct object.