# Adding post_type to the query via pre_get_posts, with infinite scroll

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm doing something wrong here.

I'm trying to add a custom post type, external-videos, to the main blog query in all instances. It's working in the main blog page *for the first load of posts* but the custom post type is ignored in subsequent posts loaded by infinite scroll. Only "regular" posts are loaded thereafter.

I'm using the wp plugin version of infinite scroll. Here's my function:

```
// add external-videos to the loop

function add_external_videos_to_query( $query ) {

    if ( is_main_query() && is_home() )
        set_query_var ( 'post_type', array('post','external-videos') );
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_external_videos_to_query' );
```

Also, seemingly related - the custom post_type is being ignored by infinite scroll even on the archive page for that custom post type. In other words, on the archive page for "external videos," the first page of "external videos" posts loads, but no further posts of that type load via infinite scroll.

Infinite scroll is working correctly for all other archives I've tested.

Incidentally I've read Mike Schinkel's reply [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28670/pre-get-posts-firing-on-every-query) and I think i'm using a similar technique, but I'm not sure if i need **`global $wp_the_query`** or not.

For another situation, but also trying to get pre_get_posts to fire every query, he said:

> Basically what you are looking for is the global $wp_the_query
>   variable which is set to the value of the main query. It may not be a
>   perfect fit for 100% of cases but will probably work fine in 99% of
>   cases:
>
> ```
> add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_post_count' );
> function custom_post_count( $query ){
>   global $wp_the_query;
>   if ( $wp_the_query === $query ) {
>     $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 5 );
>   }
>   return $query;
> };
> ```

Comment: `is_main_query` was added in WP3.3 as a shortcut for checking `$wp_the_query === $query`, it's doing the same thing behind the scenes.

Comment: Thanks. yes, that's what i inferred from Mike's comment below his post. I must be missing something else, or else infinite scroll somehow skips pre_get_posts?

Comment: I'm beginning to think this may be an issue with the way the infinite scroll plugin accesses wp_query.

Answer (score 0):

@nimmolo since we solved this, we should leave for posterity that the solution had nothing to do with `pre_get_posts`.  We needed to check the post class selectors for the video posts were the same as for regular posts.

Comment: Yes - sorry. This question is resolved, I had the post class selectors specified incorrectly for the custom post type.